# How to transform a nested array into a table in ksqldb/kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I started learning ksqldb for Kafka and ran into a problem, I have a Product stream and the structure is the following:

```
 ID          | VARCHAR(STRING)
 NAME        | VARCHAR(STRING)
 ...
 INGREDIENTS | ARRAY<STRUCT<NAME VARCHAR(STRING), ISALLERGEN BOOLEAN, RELATIVEAMOUNT DOUBLE>>
```

And as a result, I want to create a table and get the last state of the product using 'LATEST_BY_OFFSET' function, but the problem is that I can't apply this function to Array or Struct.

Should I EXPLODE each prop and create a separate entry in the table for each ingredient?(I think it's very strange). How can I deal with this situation? Can you tell me if you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved in release 0.25.1
https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/8878
https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/commit/adac45855dce1c413073e5cbeb474cb022013a2b

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.  It is documented here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5437 and I happen to be working on it presently.  Hopefully a solution will be available in an upcoming version!

I'm not sure how your workaround would work given that after you explode the array that there could be several instance of each component of the struct per key...

Comment: but maybe you have options, how can we solve such a case? maybe some custom solutions?

Comment: Presently, UDAFs that you could create and add to ksqldb (running locally; user code is not permitted in Confluent Cloud at this time) would need to take one input type and have fixed aggregate and return types.  

If you really wanted to, you could read through https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/ksqldb-engine/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/function/udaf/offset/LatestByOffset.java and write a custom LatestByOffset for the type `ARRAY<STRUCT<NAME VARCHAR(STRING), ISALLERGEN BOOLEAN, RELATIVEAMOUNT DOUBLE>>`.  It'd be a decent bit of work, but it is possible.